# jQuery : point circle set position menu hover/hover out and click navigation link

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Jquery** : here is what i have coded but its not work perfect, i need to when i click on menu the active circle stay active link and not go back to top .

1. When hover nav link circle dot come there
2. When click on nav link circle dot stay active link
3. When link is active and circle dot there after hover any another link the circle dot goes to there and go back to active link

If you have and suggestion or solution please give me answer

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   
 var activelenght = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a").length;
 var activelenghtfirst = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li#secmain.active a").length;
 var moveobj = jQuery(".nav_active_dot");
 var activeobj = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a");
 var activeobjoff = activeobj.offset().top;
 var activeparentoff = activeobj.parent().parent().offset().top;
 var finaloffactive = activeobjoff-activeparentoff;
 if (activelenghtfirst > 0) {
  jQuery(moveobj).css("top",finaloffactive);
  jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity",1);
 } else {
  jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity",0);
 }
 jQuery(".navigation_box ul li a").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).mouseover(function () {
   var obj = jQuery(this);
   var childPos = obj.offset();
   var parentPos = obj.parent().parent().offset();
   var childOffset =  childPos.top - parentPos.top;
   jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity",1);
   jQuery(moveobj).css("top",childOffset);
  });
  jQuery(this).mouseout(function() {
   if( activelenghtfirst > 0) {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("top",0);
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity",0);
    console.log("2");
   } else {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("top",0);
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity",0);
   }
  });
  jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
   jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
  });
   });
  });
```

```css
* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;}
 .navigation_box { font-family:arial; position:relative;}
 .navigation_box ul { display:block; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative;}
 .navigation_box ul li { display:block; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative;}
 .navigation_box ul li a { color:#000; margin:0; padding:7px 0 7px 30px; font-size:14px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; position:relative; text-decoration:none;}
 .navigation_box ul li a .circle_border { width:10px; height:10px; border-radius:50px; background:#fff; border:solid 1px #000; position:absolute; left:0; top:10px; z-index:1;}
 .navigation_box ul li.active a { color:#47c5f3;}
 .navigation_box ul li a:hover { color:#47c5f3;}
 .navigation_box ul li a:after { position:absolute; left:5px; width:1px; content:''; background:#000; height:30px; top:19px;}
 .navigation_box ul li:last-child a:after { display:none;}
 .navigation_box .nav_active_dot { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:10px; height:10px; background:#47c5f3; border-radius:20px; margin:10px 0 0 0; opacity:0; z-index:2;
  -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="navigation_box">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" id="secmain" style="opacity:0; visibility:hidden;"><span class="circle_border"></span>Who we are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="secwho"><span class="circle_border"></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="secbes"><span class="circle_border"></span>Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="secfac"><span class="circle_border"></span>Factor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="sectra"><span class="circle_border"></span>Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="secfor"><span class="circle_border"></span>Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="secnew"><span class="circle_border"></span>News</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav_active_dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make you *active bullet* blue using:

```
.navigation_box ul li.active a .circle_border {
  background: #47c5f3;
  border: 1px solid #47c5f3;
}
```

See demo below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var activelenght = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a").length;
  var activelenghtfirst = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li#secmain.active a").length;
  var moveobj = jQuery(".nav_active_dot");
  var activeobj = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a");
  var activeobjoff = activeobj.offset().top;
  var activeparentoff = activeobj.parent().parent().offset().top;
  var finaloffactive = activeobjoff - activeparentoff;
  if (activelenghtfirst > 0) {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("top", finaloffactive);
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 1);
  } else {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 0);
  }
  jQuery(".navigation_box ul li a").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
      var obj = jQuery(this);
      var childPos = obj.offset();
      var parentPos = obj.parent().parent().offset();
      var childOffset = childPos.top - parentPos.top;
      jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 1);
      jQuery(moveobj).css("top", childOffset);
    });
    jQuery(this).mouseout(function() {
      if (activelenghtfirst > 0) {
        jQuery(moveobj).css("top", 0);
        jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 0);
        console.log("2");
      } else {
        jQuery(moveobj).css("top", 0);
        jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 0);
      }
    });
    jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
      jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation_box {
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul li a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation_box ul li a .circle_border {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation_box ul li.active a {
  color: #47c5f3;
}

.navigation_box ul li.active a .circle_border { /* added */
  background: #47c5f3;
  border: 1px solid #47c5f3;
}

.navigation_box ul li a:hover {
  color: #47c5f3;
}

.navigation_box ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 1px;
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  top: 19px;
}

.navigation_box ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

.navigation_box .nav_active_dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #47c5f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation_box">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="secmain" style="opacity:0; visibility:hidden;"><span class="circle_border"></span>Who we are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secwho"><span class="circle_border"></span>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secbes"><span class="circle_border"></span>Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secfac"><span class="circle_border"></span>Factor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="sectra"><span class="circle_border"></span>Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secfor"><span class="circle_border"></span>Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secnew"><span class="circle_border"></span>News</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="nav_active_dot"></div>
</div>
```

But you've said this:

> When link is active and circle dot there after hover any another link
>   the circle dot goes to there and go back to active link

In that case you can use a variable (say `homePos` in the demo below) to set the *default position*. You can go back to this *default position* on `mouseout` and then *set* this on *active link* - see below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var homePos = 0;
  var activelenght = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a").length;
  var activelenghtfirst = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li#secmain.active a").length;
  var moveobj = jQuery(".nav_active_dot");
  var activeobj = jQuery(".navigation_box ul li.active a");
  var activeobjoff = activeobj.offset().top;
  var activeparentoff = activeobj.parent().parent().offset().top;
  var finaloffactive = activeobjoff - activeparentoff;
  if (activelenghtfirst > 0) {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("top", finaloffactive);
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 1);
  } else {
    jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 0);
  }
  jQuery(".navigation_box ul li a").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
      var obj = jQuery(this);
      var childPos = obj.offset();
      var parentPos = obj.parent().parent().offset();
      var childOffset = childPos.top - parentPos.top;
      jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", 1);
      jQuery(moveobj).css("top", childOffset);
    });
    jQuery(this).mouseout(function() {
        jQuery(moveobj).css("top", homePos); /* changed */
        jQuery(moveobj).css("opacity", homePos); /* changed */
    });
    jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
      jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
      
      /* added below */
      var obj = jQuery(this);
      var childPos = obj.offset();
      var parentPos = obj.parent().parent().offset();
      homePos = childPos.top - parentPos.top;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation_box {
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation_box ul li a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation_box ul li a .circle_border {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation_box ul li.active a {
  color: #47c5f3;
}

.navigation_box ul li a:hover {
  color: #47c5f3;
}

.navigation_box ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 1px;
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  top: 19px;
}

.navigation_box ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

.navigation_box .nav_active_dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #47c5f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation_box">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="secmain" style="opacity:0; visibility:hidden;"><span class="circle_border"></span>Who we are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secwho"><span class="circle_border"></span>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secbes"><span class="circle_border"></span>Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secfac"><span class="circle_border"></span>Factor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="sectra"><span class="circle_border"></span>Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secfor"><span class="circle_border"></span>Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="secnew"><span class="circle_border"></span>News</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="nav_active_dot"></div>
</div>
```